# a border like this (like some borders in tooltips) with CSS

Tags: html, css

Can I create a border like this with CSS?

[image]

It needs to be dynamic (as different text will be displayed in this box).

I know about CSS Triangles, but I am not sure if that would help me here.

Comment: Check this out - http://www.cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: @LuisP.A. thanks perfekt. add this as answer and I will accept